# dataTable filtering: hide elements (don't remove from dom)

Tags: jquery, ajax, search, filter, datatable

is there a simple way of having the datatable search filter to only hide elements that don't match the performed search and not remove them from the dom?

I am allowing users to perform searches even when other data is being loaded by ajax, which looks for the dom element to put the data inside it. With the default behaviour though, insert fails as the dom element doesn't exist anymore.

To be a little more specific: I am fetching data and putting it into a datatable, each row gets an id. Afterwards, I do ajax asynchronous calls to multiple servers that return values which should go in columns of a row with the correspondent id. This all works fine, unless you start searching before this new set of data has been inserted: when the ajax call completes it's task, it cannot find the row to append the data it retrieved, as the row has been removed from the dom.

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Could you post your code or create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: It's a bit too specific and complex to get it to work in jsfiddle.. I have added some details to the main message in which I hopefully explain myself better. Thanks :)

Comment: there is options for overcome this problem: 1. avoid the search functionality until the asynchronous are not complete, by enabling the search function in ajax callback function. 2.Clone your complete dataTable DOM structure at the time of when search functionality is used and refer to this cloned DOM structure  when asynchronous is complete and process it based on your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had already thought of solution one but it is a bit limiting, as you have to wait for all data to load (which takes a while). I'll try to give a go at the second solution you have suggested and see if I can get it working. Thanks again